# Why two O/Ss on the same machine have a 1 hour clock difference?

Tags: windows-7, linux, date-time

My machine has two O/S, a Linux distribution (primary) and a Windows 7 (used seldomly).

Both O/Ss are set on my time zone (UTC+1).

Depending on how I set the time on the BIOS, either Windows shows the time as 1 hour before the current time, or Linux 1 hour after.

Why does this happen?

The Windows machine generally starts disconnected from Internet; the Linux one instead is connected, so it corrects the date after a short time, but after rebooting, it's misconfigured again.

EDIT: Found it to be a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/16107/why-does-ubuntu-9-04-reset-my-windows-clock

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple issues that may be at play here.

First, you may have daylight savings time enabled in one and not the other, or one of your OSes is configured for the wrong time zone.

Linux may be assuming your computer's hardware clock is set to UTC instead of local, and Windows may think it's set to local. If you're at UTC+1 or UTC-1, you may see that behavior. Linux may be loading the hardware clock's value, adjusting it to be local, then transforming it back to UTC before writing to the hardware clock at shutdown time.

Comment: Time zones are correct for both, but you're right with the fact the the two O/Ss interpret the hardware clock in different ways. Not sure how I should fix it.

Comment: Solution found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/16107/why-does-ubuntu-9-04-reset-my-windows-clock

Comment: @Marcus does it survive reboot? if so, congrats. Looks like I was too late. :\ - also `/etc/default/rcS` is not present on all systems - I think it is Ubuntu-specific. Debian (which Ubuntu is derived from) does not have it.

Comment: It did survive! I'm very happy, as, although rarely, sometimes I used to forget it (being 1 hour late is quite troublesome...)

Comment: @Marcus glad to hear it then. Happy you got it working. It was confusing for me sometimes. Especially when I moved timezones

Answer (score 1):

Your linux distro is assuming your BIOS clock is using UTC, and your windows install is assuming that your BIOS time is in local time.

Here's how I have it set up on my laptop with a dual-boot:
I make the changes linux-side to use localtime instead of UTC for the system clock.
first, run a command so that the time is set properly linux-side, as `root`:

```
date -s "2 feb 2016 18:05:15"
```

`hwclock --hctosys --localtime` should copy the BIOS date/time settings to your computer and set them to the local time. `hwclock --systohc --localtime` should set the BIOS time in localtime instead of UTC. I would recommend setting the time with the `date` command above, then running:
    hwclock --systohc --localtime
AND ALSO running:
    hwclock --hctosys --localtime
to make sure /etc/adjtime has the last line of the file saying 'LOCAL' instead of 'UTC' or anything like that. the `--hctosys --localtime` flags together can accomplish that programmatically. It's possible that `date` will do it alone, but I've not checked.

to check that the system time is indeed accurate in localtime.
Don't fret over how the date setting string is formatted, it's extremely flexible. As an example of other valid ways to say it:

```
date -s "2 feb 2016 6:05:15 PM"
date -s "february 2, 2016 6:11:30 PM"
date -s "Tue Feb  2 18:11:30 EST 2016"
```

(I'm in Eastern Standard time, GMT -5)

If you still have trouble, you may need to re-select a timezone.
In Debian or derivatives like Ubuntu, you use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to change timezones in a ncurses interface.

If you don't have that, try to find your relevant timezone information file. On my install this is `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Indiana/Indianapolis`.

Once you've found it, copy that over to `/etc/localtime`:

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Indiana/Indianapolis /etc/localtime
```

I'd make sure the time is still set with `date` properly after doing this. If it's not, run the first two commands (`date` and `hwclock`) again.

in linux should make it so whatever time you set in linux is shared with windows properly. Alternatively, it can be done but is harder to instead set windows to use UTC. How this is done changes with versions and windows has been known to revert back to localtime after updates.

I remember one particularly stubborn computer where doing all the `hwclock` stuff was getting overriden, because the computer was fetching the current time over the internet with NTP. The time zone setting was the only way to fix that without disabling NTP altogether.

Anyway, that's just a big dump of all my past experiences with the matter. One of those will almost definitely work. I'd try the timezone stuff first, and then definitely try the `hwclock --systohc --localtime` stuff after you're done to make sure the BIOS clock is in local time.